# MySQL select all users who have not logged in for 30 days

Tags: mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

I have a table that has a user id & timestamp, like the following.

```
[member id] [timestamp]
1            1142461087
1            1339461211
2            1321280124
1            1249042100
3            1308325002
3            1308259235
```

I want to return a list of unique member ids who have not logged in for 30 days or longer.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT member_id, login_timestamp
  FROM logins 
  WHERE login_timestamp <= 1329461087
  GROUP BY member_id
  ORDER BY login_timestamp DESC
```

I thought this was correct, but for some reason, in production, the admin user's ID shows up on the list, which is not possible since admin logs every day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
SELECT member_id, MAX(login_timestamp)
FROM logins 
GROUP BY member_id
HAVING MAX(login_timestamp) <= 1329461087
ORDER BY MAX(login_timestamp) DESC
```

Comment: I forgot all about MAX() and just didn't know about HAVING. thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of hard-coding the cutoff time, try

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE login_timestamp <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP((NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY))
...
```

As for your admin account - when does the login timestamp get updated? And is there special-caseing done when an admin account does log in?

Comment: the login timestamp is added to the logins table upon the completion of the login redirecting to the inner website.

Answer (score 2):

You could take all users and remove those that have logged in in the last 30 days. The result will be those users who have not logged in in the last 30 days:

```
select distinct t1.id
from t t1
where not exists (
  select * from t t2
  where t1.id = t2.id and 
  timestamp >= unix_timestamp((curdate() - interval 30 day))
)
```

Comment: I stumbled back across this solution years after you gave it. Can you mention when this particular approach would be more helpful than simply selecting those who are within the 30 day group? is there performance difference either way?